# FeinCMS, intermediate model on content type field

Tags: django, feincms

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
class DownloadContentFiles(models.Model):
    download_content = models.ForeignKey('DownloadContent')
    media_file = models.ForeignKey(MediaFile)

class DownloadContent(models.Model):
    files = models.ManyToManyField(MediaFile, through=DownloadContentFiles)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

I can see why this doesn't work. Because of the abstract on DownloadContent.

Is there a workaround to specify a intermediate model for contenttype fields?

Comment: Your ``DownloadContentFiles`` is not a subclass of ``models.Model``

Comment: Oh, yes, that should have been in the question already. Not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you need more informations when creating a field (such as a list of choices) or a concrete Django model (as you do), you can use `initialize_type` for that.

```
class DownloadContent(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def initialize_type(cls):
        cls.add_to_class('files', ... your model field ...)
```

The `MediaFileContent` uses this method to add the `type` selector:

https://github.com/feincms/feincms/blob/master/feincms/content/medialibrary/models.py#L58

**However**, in your case this does not work because you'd also have to create the `through` model dynamically. The reason for that is that for each concrete `DownloadContent`, you'd need another concrete `DownloadContentFiles` model.

You could achieve this by using the `type` built-in to dynamically create new `DownloadContentFiles` concrete classes (beware of name clashes when using `DownloadContent` with different CMS bases such as `page.Page` and `elephantblog.Entry`).

**Maybe a simpler way to achieve what you want:**

- Add a `Downloads` model somewhere, and add the `files` `ManyToManyField` to this class instead
- The `DownloadContent` only contains a `ForeignKey(Downloads)`

Yes, you need another model. It might be worth it because you can build a better editing interface for `Downloads`, and the page editor is also simplified because you only have to select one of the already existing `Downloads` models for showing them on a page.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to implement the 'dynamically creating new DownloadContentFiles for each DownloadContent' part. Can I do this in initialize_type? I will go with the simpeler way for now.

Comment: You can create new types using `type()`, but you probably shouldn't. I hope that the simpler way works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe explicitely defining `class_name` to [create_content_type](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/api/core.html?highlight=class_name#base-models) could work for you. Something like this:

```
class DownloadContentFiles(models.Model):
    download_content = models.ForeignKey('MyDownloadContent')
    media_file = models.ForeignKey(MediaFile)

class DownloadContent(models.Model):
   files = models.ManyToManyField(MediaFile, through=DownloadContentFiles)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

Page.create_content_type(DownloadContent, class_name="MyDownloadContent")
```